# Specify eclipse workspace from command line at eclipse invocation

Tags: eclipse

I want to specify the desired work-space on the command line when I invoke Eclipse. I have read the command line documentation and found it totally opaque. What command line argument do I need?

Comment: `eclipse -data <path-to-workspace>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workspace is specified using the `-data` argument:

```
-data /path/to/workspace
```

There are some special values you can use, the most useful being`@user.home` for the user's home directory

```
-data @user.home/myworkspace
```

Full details in the [Eclipse run time options](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) help page